# Is "Which country are you guys at?" correct?

Tags: word-choice, syntactic-analysis

I'm not sure whether this sentence is right.
" Which country are you guys at?" I said this without any hesitation but ... I don't think it's right. I'm not 100% sure.

So my own corrections are:

1. Which country are you guys from?
2. Which country are you guys in?

I'd like to know how I can put this more naturally.
What else can I say that would be correct?

Comment: Both your corrections are grammatical, but mean different things.  Can you describe the situation you are talking about?

Comment: I was looking at the live instagram and asking for where they were ☺ could you please explain the differences? Thank you so much !

Comment: In fact the situation here is that on of my friends told me that he is in a foreign country but he didn't name it. So I wanted to ask him in which country he is in. Would it be correct to say " which country you are touring?" Or "which country you are in?"

Answer (score 2):

"At" is bad, because a country is a large thing.  "At" is best with points (no area or volume).  However, there are special contexts that would make sense of "Which country are you at?".  If you were going through a file of visa applications in a file that was organized by country, for instance, you might be at Germany in the file but not yet come to Honduras.

"In" is best with things that have volume, or at least can contain things -- rooms, swimming pools, cars.

However, there many idiomatic uses of "in/on/at" that don't seem to obey any overall logic.

Comment: Oh..... I didn't know that. Thank you so much 

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context of the conversation, if you are talking to a friend whom you know a simple “where are you?” would be correct, and if this person is a stranger also a simple “where are you from?” would be correct also.
In a non-formal context, you can say “in which country are you guys?” or, “from which country are you guys?”
Merry Christmas

Answer (score -1):

Your sentence is fine for informal spoken American. I take it that you're young and so are the guys you're addressing so a slang construction works. If you want to retain the slangy young feel you could go with 'Hey, guys. Where are you from?'

Comment: This is not correct. Excepting contexts that deal with a list of countries (as in Greg’s answer above), “Which country are you guys at?” is ungrammatical in English, whether formal or informal, spoken or written, American or otherwise.